# Order by maximum match in fulltext

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to search records in a table:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q')   LIMIT 15
```

It returns first 15 results, how can I sort this by the order of maximum number of matches?

Comment: Maximum number of matches is where `MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q') > 0`

Comment: @Rahul R choose answer, its helpful to close the issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q') AS mat 
  FROM posts 
  WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q') ORDER BY mat LIMIT 15
  ORDER BY mat DESC
```

You can add ascending or descending order by adding `ORDER BY mat DESC` **or** `ORDER BY mat`

Comment: desc missing ( i think so )

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT *,MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q') AS relevance FROM posts WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$q') ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 15
```